# Vue: share a vue element between child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-xxn73s?file=/src/App.vue

[image]

I have two `Vue` components that make use of the same `HappyDog.vue` component: `HumanJoe.vue` and `AlienBob.vue`. `HappyDog.vue` emits events when its inner state (the number of apples) changes (randomly increases or decreases). In a bigger project the components that use `HappyDog` could change its inner state by passing reactive data as props.

I'd like to be able to use the same `HappyDog` component in several other components, so that all components that use `HappyDog` reference the same component, with the same number of apples.

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <HumanJoe />

  <AlienBob />
</template>

<script>
import HumanJoe from "./components/HumanJoe.vue";
import AlienBob from "./components/AlienBob.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HumanJoe: HumanJoe,
    AlienBob: AlienBob,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**HappyDog.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div class="dog">
    <b>Dog with {{ this.apples }} apples</b>

    <div class="dog-apples">
      <div class="apple" v-for="a in this.apples" :key="a"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {},

  data() {
    return {
      apples: 100,
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.changeApples(), 3000);
  },

  methods: {
    changeApples() {
      let add = 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1; // [1, 2]

      let random = 0;
      if (add) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; // [1, 100]

        this.apples += random;

        this.$emit("gain", this.apples);
      } else {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1; // [1, 50]

        this.apples -= random;

        if (this.apples < 0) {
          this.apples = 0;

          this.$emit("loss", this.apples);
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dog {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  background-color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;

  overflow: scroll;
}

.dog-apples {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 5px;
}

.apple {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;

  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

and the components that make use of the `HappyDog.vue` - they are almost entirely the same, for simplicity, but in a bigger project they could have their own rules as to how they react to events emmited from `HappyDog`, and possible change the state of `HappyDog`:

**HumanJoe.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div class="joe">
    <b> Joe </b>
    <HappyDog />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import HappyDog from "./HappyDog.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HappyDog: HappyDog,
  },
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.joe {
  background-color: cyan;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
}

.joe b {
  font-size: 200%;
}
</style>
```

**AlienBob.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div class="bob">
    <b> Bob </b>
    <HappyDog />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import HappyDog from "./HappyDog.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HappyDog: HappyDog,
  },
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.bob {
  background-color: lime;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
}

.bob b {
  font-size: 200%;
}
</style>
```

I realize that in this simple example I could make different `HappyDog` components inside `HumanJoe` and `AlienBob` have the same number of apples, by passing a reactive prop that would get updated inside `App.vue`, or use emitted events to update an `apples` data in `App.vue` that would get passed as a prop to `HumanJoe` and `AlienBob`, however, I'd really like to be able for them both to just use the same `HappyDog` component, if it's at all possible.

I've searched for it, and found slots and `is`, but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for as I couldn't find the examples of sharing the same component, rather than dynamically passing a name of a component to create.

Comment: Have you considered Pinia?

Comment: Laso you cant have both vue2 and vue3 tags plz fix

Answer (score 3):

When your Vue app is transitioning to something that has heavy coupling between components via props, as in your case, it is best to use state management.

State management has a global "store" where you can define the state (or multiple states), view (getters) and actions (setters). With this management model, you can hold "global" data that can be shared across multiple components. [Read more about it here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern).

An example of this is storing user session info (i.e. username, email, etc.), or in your case, apple data (state) which can be accessed (view) and changed (action).

Vuex is usually the go-to, but that has [transitioned to Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) - so I recommend using that.

Answer (score 1):

As described, a state management is extremely useful. Another solution is creating your own composable functions instead of using a store library e.g. **Pinia**.

A good explanation you find in this article: https://michael-verschoof.medium.com/keep-state-easily-using-a-composable-in-vue-3-2e01b2c68d7f